# Simple game in C++ involving a dice and bolts

Tags: c++, dice

I have been working on a simple game in c++. the game consists of a dice and several players. the number of players may very between 1-4 and as long as each of them has 2-4 bolts.

> singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the instantiation to a certain number of objects. The term comes from the mathematical concept of a singleton.

My code does its work and gets the job done. But I'm wondering if there's a 'better' way to do this. 
I hope I can get some tips on how to structure or approach this task.

Simply is there a shorter code that I can write for this.

- I aim to rewrite the whole class in an easier/simpler way for education purpose)? Please feel free to share you answer :)

Header:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>

class CGamer;
class CDie;

class CGame
{
public:
    static CGame* instance();
    ~CGame();

    int createGamers(const int numPlayers);
    void play(const bool interactive);

protected:
    CGame();

private:
    void waitForInput(const bool interactive);
    QString playerName(const int plId) const;
    int setNextGamerToMove();
    void updateAllOtherPegsState();
    int convertPosition(const int position,
                        CGamer* currentPlayer,
                        CGamer* targetPlayer) const;

private:
    static CGame* mInstance;

    CDie* mDie;
    CGamer *mGamerToMove;

    QVector<CGamer*> mGamers;
    QVector<CGamer*> mFinishedGamers;

private:
    friend class tst_CGame;
};

#endif // COMPETITION_H
```

Source:

```
CGame* CGame::mInstance = 0;

CGame::CGame()
    : mDie(0),
      mGamerToMove(0),
      mGamers(0),
      mFinishedGamers(0)
{
    mGamers.clear();
    mFinishedGamers.clear();
    mDie = CDie::instance();
}

CGame::~CGame()
{
    foreach (CGamer* gamer, mFinishedGamers) {
        delete gamer;
        gamer = 0;
    }

    // Deleted in the for loop above
    //delete mGamerToMove; mGamerToMove = 0;

    delete mDie;
    mDie = 0;
}

CGame * CGame::instance()
{
    if (0 == mInstance) {
        mInstance = new CGame;
    }
    return mInstance;
}

void CGame::waitForInput(const bool interactive)
{
    if (interactive) {
        CONSOLE_LOG << "ENTER to execute a turn ";
    }

    QTextStream qin(stdin);
    forever {
        CGamer* gamerFinished = 0;

        if (interactive) {
            QString line = qin.readLine();
            if (line.isNull()) {
                K_DEBUG_LOG << "NULL line";
                break;
            }
        } else {
            CONSOLE_LOG; //empty line
        }

        mDie->pop();
        int dieValue = mDie->getFaceValue();

        CONSOLE_LOG << "Gamer" << mGamerToMove->name() << "moves";
        int moveResult = mGamerToMove->move(dieValue);
        CONSOLE_LOG << "   " << mGamers.size() << "gamers left in the game";

        if (MOVE_WAITING_FOR_6 == moveResult) {
            // all pegs are in HOME
            if (setNextGamerToMove() != RET_OK) {
                K_ERROR_LOG << "Next gamer not found. Exiting...";
                exit(1);
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (MOVE_ALL_PEGS_FINISHED == moveResult) {
            CONSOLE_LOG << "GAMER" << mGamerToMove->name() << "FINISHED!";
            gamerFinished = mGamerToMove;
            mFinishedGamers.push_back(mGamerToMove);
        }

        updateAllOtherBoltsState();

        do {
            if (setNextGamerToMove() != RET_OK) {
                K_ERROR_LOG << "Next gamer not found. Exiting...";
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        } while (mGamerToMove->finished() && (mGamers.size() > 2));

        if (gamerFinished) {
            mGamers.remove(mGamers.indexOf(gamerFinished));
            gamerFinished = 0;
        }

        if (mGamers.size() == 1) {
            // one gamer left in the game, so he's the last one
            mFinishedGamers.push_back(mGamerToMove);
            CONSOLE_LOG ;
            CONSOLE_LOG << "-----------";
            CONSOLE_LOG << "GAME OVER!";
            CONSOLE_LOG << "-----------";
            CONSOLE_LOG << "Ranking:";
            int i = 1;
            foreach (CGamer* gamer, mFinishedGamers) {
                CONSOLE_LOG << i << ": gamer" << gamer->name();
                ++i;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

void CGame::updateAllOtherBoltsState()
{
    int movedPosition = mGamerToMove->lastPegsPosition();
    foreach (CGamer* gamer, mGamers) {
        if (gamer == mGamerToMove) {
            // The gamer that just moved definitely doesn't have any bolt on the moved position
            continue;
        }
        int targetPosition = convertPosition(movedPosition, mGamerToMove, gamer);
        int status = gamer->updateBoltsState(targetPosition);
        if (UPDATE_STATE_DONE == status) {
            // no more updates needed
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int CGame::setNextGamerToMove()
{
    int currentPosition = mGamers.indexOf(mGamerToMove);
    if (-1 == currentPosition) {
        K_ERROR_LOG << "Gamer not found in the list!";
        return RET_NOK;
    }
    if ((mDie->getFaceValue() == DIE_NUMBER_SIX)
         && !(mGamerToMove->finished())) {
        // same gamer moves again, if there are more pegs not in FINISHED
        // do nothing
        return RET_OK;
    }

    if (mGamers.size() == 1) {
        // last gamer in the game, so will move again, do nothing
        return RET_OK;
    }
    int nextPosition = (currentPosition + 1) % mGamers.size();
    mGamerToMove = mGamers.at(nextPosition);
    return RET_OK;
}

void CGame::play(const bool interactive)
{
    mGamerToMove = mGamers.at(0);
    waitForInput(interactive);
}

int CGame::createGamers(const int numPlayers)
{
    if ((numPlayers) < 2 || (numPlayers > 4)) {
        return RET_NOK;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
        CGamer* gamer = new CGamer(gamerName(i));
        mGamers.push_back(gamer);
    }
    return RET_OK;
}

QString CGame::gamerName(const int plId) const
{
    QStringList gamers;
    gamers << "A" << "B" << "C" << "D";
    return gamers.at(plId);
}

// Convert the position from currentgamer's coordinates
// into targetGamer's coordinates
int CGame::convertPosition(const int position,
                           CGamer *currentgamer,
                           CGamer *targetGamer) const
{
    if ((position < 1) || (position >= FIRST_FINISH_POSITION)) {
        return -1;
    }

    int targetPosition = -1;

    int currentGamerId = mGamers.indexOf(currentgamer);
    int targetPlayerId = mGamers.indexOf(targetGamer);

    if (currentGamerId == targetPlayerId) {
        return position;
    }

    int multiplier = NUM_OF_SIDES - (targetPlayerId - currentGamerId);
    // 28 overlapping holes (before finish line)
    targetPosition = (position + multiplier * NUM_OF_HOLES_PER_SIDE) % LAST_OVERLAPPING_HOLE;
    if (0 == targetPosition) {
        // result of % 28 is 0 => hole number 28
        targetPosition = LAST_OVERLAPPING_HOLE;
    }
    return targetPosition;
}
```

**[Download my Header and Source Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjbQDEh-nyvemdLbHBPOTRVN2M)**

Comment: `foreach`, `forever`, seems someone tried to #define their own private language in the part you snipped off. You know, things are easier if what you post compiles as-is. All the includes and declarations are important.

Comment: Please add the header file (or class declaration).

Answer (score 6):

### Code Review

#### The Singleton Pattern.

Ahh. The pattern. A nice interesting pattern but usually always the wrong solution. In my twenty years I have used this pattern three times in production. Twice I was wrong. I forget if the third time was wrong. But the point being this is usually not a good solution.

The problem with Singleton is the tight coupling of the object that is used. Thus it becomes extremely hard to test. To use the Singleton correctly you **MUST** combine it with another builder pattern so that you can use different singleton (i.e. one for testing, one for production, one when you want to customize, you still have a single object that represents your thing but which one is instantiated depends on configuration.). Using the Singleton in isolation becomes a real problem for testing.

OK. Lets assume you actually want a singleton then you should do it correctly.

```
CGame * CGame::instance()
{
    if (0 == mInstance) {
        mInstance = new CGame;
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

This bit of code has so many issues.

1. Who is responsible for deleting the singleton?
   i.e what are the ownership semantics. Given the above design you can not tell if the caller should delete it or the singleton will auto destroy. Even if you delete it (which is the correct behavior) you can not tell if you deleted them at the correct time.

There are a couple of solutions.

- You can let the class retain ownership and manage deletion, in which case you return `CGame&`
- You can have shared ownership in which case you need to return a `std::shared_ptr<CGame>`

Personally I prefer method 1. Which leads to this code:

```
CGame& CGame::getInstance()
{
    // Note static function member.
    // This is created on first call. It is a static storage duration
    // object so it lives until the end of the program (after main()
    // terminates).
    static CGame  instance;

    // return a reference to the object.
    return instance;
}
```

For lots more detail see this article I wrote:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

2. The current implementation is not thread safe.
3. Comparison test against `0` is not good. You should be using `nullptr`
4. To prevent random creation of this object you need to make the constructors and assignment operators private (not protected).

   ```
   // This is not good enough
   protected:
       CGame();

   // You need this.
   private:
       CGame();
       CGame(CGame const&)        = delete;
       CGame& operator=(CGame&)   = delete;
       CGame(CGame&&)             = delete;
       CGame& operator=(CGame&&)  = delete;
   ```

But now we have covered the singleton. I would point out that better way to do this is to create the object in main. Then pass the object to each function that used it by reference.

```
int main()
{
    CGame   theGame;

    theGame.createGamers(4);
    theGame.play();
}
```

#### Return Codes

Error codes returned by a public interface is a bad design.

```
int CGame::createGamers(const int numPlayers)
{
    if ((numPlayers) < 2 || (numPlayers > 4)) {
        return RET_NOK;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
        CGamer* gamer = new CGamer(gamerName(i));
        mGamers.push_back(gamer);
    }
    return RET_OK;
}
```

It means you rely on the user of your code doing so correctly and checking the error code. In the past 30 years of programming has shown this is not a good idea. People just do not check error codes and this causes the code to continue executing in the presence of an error.

Now error codes internally to your class is fine (so private methods can return error codes because you know your code and will check error codes you just can't trust other people so you can't put this in a public interface).

A better technique is to throw an exception if there is a problem. This will result in the application terminating unless the person using your code explicitly writes the code to check for the error (this is much more appropriate as code can not continue to run with the program in a bad state).

```
void CGame::createGamers(const int numPlayers)
{
    if ((numPlayers) < 2 || (numPlayers > 4)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
    }
```

#### Containers can take objects

It is usually not a good idea to store pointers in a container (they don't convey ownership semantics, i.e. who should delete them). So if you must store a pointer in a container then you should at least wrap it in a smart pointer so we know who should be deleting it.

```
 QVector<std::unique_ptr<CGamer>> mGamers;
```

But unless you need polymorphic objects in the container (and you don't seem to need this). The you should probably just store the object in the container.

```
    QVector<CGamer> mGamers;

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
        mGamers.push_back(std::move(CGamer(gamerName(i))));
    }
```

Now you have the object itself in a container and don't need to worry about any memory management.

Question: Is there a reason why you use `QVector` instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: Good review!  I strongly agree that using a singleton is **absolutely**  the wrong choice in this case.  I'd add that the apparent design of `CDie` is also in need of rethinking.  It has (apparently) a static `instance()` member that returns a pointer, and `pop()` and `getFaceValue()` member functions that suggest a rather muddled design.